# Hibernate takes a long time to query a database View

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Dev. Environment: `Spring Boot 1.5 + Hibernate + SQL Server 2014`

Driver: `Microsoft Driver [version: mssql-jdbc 6.2.1.jre8]`

Whenever I query a Table, Hibernate returns the data almost instantaneously.
However, when I query a View in the same database - (but the View is defined to bring data from another database), it always seems to take forever.

It was taking 2 seconds per lookup, which is unacceptable when 100s of records need to be retrieved from the database. Therefore, I changed the code to use `IN(List<String> queryParamList)` so as to limit the database trips to one. However, though this query is very quick compared to the 8 minutes it was taking before, now it still takes 30 seconds, which is still unacceptable.

Here are the things I have tried so far:

1. Used `@Query` instead of letting Spring Data/Hibernate build the query.
2. Following the suggestions elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I added an all-argument `Constructor` (omitted the `@Transient` fields from this).
3. Used a native query in the `CRUDRepository`.

None of the above are helping to reduce the response times.

When I copy the Hibernate query from the console output and run it against the View in SQL Server Management Studio, the results are returned instantaneously.

When I monitor the activity on the database, as soon as the line gets executed in the IDE, I see it pop up in the database' Activity Monitor. It just sits there for the same 30 seconds and then returns the data. Even SQL Server identifies this as an expensive query.

What else can I try? Any suggestions?

Any insights/help is much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT**:
*Datasource Config. in application.properties*:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://MRR-SQL8:1433;database=ECA2;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2014Dialect
```

*Controller code*:

```
empCandidate.setEmpView(empViewRepository.findOne(empCandidate.getApplication().getEmpNumber()));
```

*Hibernate query from console output*:

```
select empview0_.empnum as empnum1_37_0_, empview0_.address1 as address2_37_0_, empview0_.address2 as address3_37_0_
from vwepsemp empview0_ 
where empview0_.gmin=?
```

Depending on the size of the resultset, the execution time keeps increasing. Right now, for a 2000-record resultset it takes 30 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried running the query against the database without using hibernate?  If the query is taking long to run when you run it directly against the database, the problem is in your view and not your hibernate configuration.

Comment: @DaShaun Yes, as I mentioned in my question, when I run the query directly on the database, it returns the results instantaneously.

Comment: Go back to whichever option you were using, that generated the SQL in console that returns instantly.  Share that code and your datasource configurations.

Comment: @DaShaun Updated my post with code snippets.

Comment: Have you defined any collection pool limits?  max idle?  keep alive?  That would be my next step.  Set values for the maxActive=100, removeAbandoned=true, removeAbandonedTimeout=10

Comment: @DaShaun Though our Production env. is WebLogic, I am currently developing/testing this with Tomcat that comes bundled with Spring Boot and devTools. I have not configured any of those settings, just using the defaults. However, the behavior is the same in both Tomcat and WebLogic.

Comment: @DaShaun I added these settings to the `application.properties` file: `spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true`. However, when I add `spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned-timeout=10` it causes an error `java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed`.

Comment: @DaShaun Couldn't fit it all in one comment...No change in execution time even with the max-active and remove-abandoned settings.

Comment: How are you making your view?

Comment: @DaShaun The View already exists in the main database (DB1). However, it contains data from another database (DB2) on a different server. Will be experimenting by moving the remote table from DB2 to DB1 and pointing the View to the now "local" table to see if that makes a difference, so that I can determine if traversing servers is the cause for the delay.